# javascript - enable a plugin if width is greater than 767px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am trying to write some javascript/jquery that will allow me to enable a slideshow plugin if the viewport width is greater than 767px.

If it is less than said value, it should simply display a background image in the body and disable the plugin

Currently i cannot get the plugin to display when the width is > 767px but the background image does show when less

any help would be appreciated

**CODE:**

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
           if($(this).width() < 767) {
               $("body").addClass("backgroundImage");
               $("#example, body").vegas();
               window.location.reload();

           } else {
               $("body").removeClass("backgroundImage");
               $("#example, body").vegas({
            delay:10000,
            transition: 'fade',
            cover: true,
            align: 'center',
            valign: 'center',
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: true,
            slides: [
                {src: "img/slideshow/img1wB-E.jpg"},
                {src: "img/slideshow/img2-2.jpg"}
            ]
        });
               window.location.reload();
               return;

           }

        }).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, please provide a working code that isolate and demonstrated your question.

Comment: You shouldn't use `.trigger("resize")`, but rather handle `load` in the event listener too (`.on("resize load")`).

Comment: @wlin - What's not clear? if width<767, display background image and disable plugin, else enable plugin and remove background image

Comment: @Jamen - the plugin still doesnt load with that - i only get the background image to work

Comment: did you try to use `.hide() and .show()` jquery ? so you  can  let your slide working all time, what you  have to do is only show the slide when > or hide when <

Comment: @RandomMath, It wasn't a solution, I'm just telling you some good practices. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a CSS entry with the min-width 767, so if its below that, it wouldn't show up.

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
    .specialSlideshow {
      width: 750px; } 
    }
@media (min-width: 0px) {
    .specialSlideshow {
      display:none; } 
    }
```

So, you could potentially wrap a div with class specialSlideshow around your slideshow code, if its below 767px, it wont show.

Comment: the slideshow code is initialised through a script not css - therefore this won't work

Comment: @RandomMath you could initialize the code inside the div.

Comment: I have just tried this however the slideshow still wont display

Comment: @RandomMath then I'm not sure, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/vegas/vegas.min.css">
> <script src="/js/vegas/vegas.min.js"></script>
> ```

in the .html?

And did you mean to delay it by 10 secs?

Comment: Yes - the slideshow works otherwise - but im trying to get it to change on mobile on pc

Comment: Try this maybe?
$(window).on('resize', function() { ... }).trigger('resize');
-->
$(window).resize(function() { ... });